# Reading Object Literal in JS with function result

Tags: javascript, object, literals

I have an object literal:

```
var content = {
    classname1:"content",
    classname2:"content"
}
```

Accessing in this way `content.classname1` is easy. But I do not want to state `classname1` rather than using a function to get that classname and pass it to my object:

```
function getMyClass {
 // some code
 return myclass;
}

content.myclass
```

where `myclass` is the result of a function. But that does not work. I do not know how to concatenate the `content.` with the result of the function.

The background is: I want tooltips to be displayed for nearly everthing on my site. So one function schould find out the class of the element and then display it the content associated to it from the object literal. So managing classname and content would be pretty easy.

Thanks.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code snippets here. Regardless, I've tried to provide you with an answer below.

Comment: It seems redundant if `getMyClass()` is a copy of `document.getElementsByTagName('name_of_class');`; what are the parameters for the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getMyClass {
    // some code
    return "myclass";
}

content["myclass"];
```

This might be what your looking for. Your question is a bit vague.

Alternatively you could try:

```
for (var key in content) {
    if (content.hasOwnProperty("key")) {
         addContent(key, content[key]);
    }
}

function addContent(className, content) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj.property` is syntactic sugar for `obj['property']`

You can access the members of an object using `[]` notation instead of dotted notation. If you use brackets, then you can place anything that evaluates to a string between the brackets. This allows you to dynamically specify properties, or to use property names that aren't valid JavaScript identifiers... for example `obj['2nd property']`

So, try:

`content[getMyClass()]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function (perhaps there's more logic than simply selecting the value of a property), here's one way:

```
var content = {
  classname1:"contentbbbb",
  classname2:"contentaaaa",
  getClassName : function(which){
    // do stuff, check things
    return this[which];
  }
}
```

Then you'd have:

```
content.getClassName('classname1'); // returns 'contentbbbb'
```

Comment: Yeah, this may be helpful in my further development... Thanks!